# ionCube Loader, returning empty screen

Tags: php, vps, ioncube

I am attempting to install ionCube on my VPS from DigitalOcean and I have ran the install and selected the appropriate options but then it simply returns a screen with the header of ionCube but then it has a banner saying "IMPORTANT: Ensure that This Script Is Removed When No Longer Required" followed by a single line of writing that says "ionCube Loader Wizard" and does nothing. In addition the application that it using ionCube says it is still not installed.

Answer (score 1):

The empty Wizard page might indicate that a few PHP functions are disabled, though without the output of your `phpinfo();` I can only guess.

DigitalOcean themselves have instructions on how to install the Loader, which can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ioncube-loader). These are applicable to most VPS with slight alterations. A rough summary in case the link isn't available:

1. Get and unpack the newest Loader on your server: (if you are not on DigitalOcean please choose your own Loaders [here](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php))

   32bit:

   ```
   wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86.tar.gz
   tar xvfz ioncube_loaders_lin_x86.tar.gz
   ```

   64bit:

   ```
   wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
   tar xvfz ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Find out your extensions directory:

   ```
   php -i | grep extension_dir
   ```

   Which will yield something like

   ```
    extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs => /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
   ```
3. Copy the Loader to the extensions directory:

   ```
   PHP_VERSION=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.'.'.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;")
   sudo cp "ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_${PHP_VERSION}.so" /your/extensions/dir
   ```

   For example with the previous output:

   ```
   PHP_VERSION=$(php -r "echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.'.'.PHP_MINOR_VERSION;")
   sudo cp "ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_${PHP_VERSION}.so" /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/
   ```
4. Add the `zend_extension` entry to your `php.ini`. This step is not described in the DigitalOcean tutorial, it seems that their PHP is set up to load any extension in the extensions directory I assume, so this might not be necessary for you.

   Find out where your php.ini file is (or better yet, plugin directory):

   ```
     php -i | grep "Loaded Config"
     php -i | grep "Scan this dir"
   ```

   You will get something like this:

   ```
    Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
    Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d
   ```

   You can either add this entry to the top of your `php.ini` (in this case in `/etc/php.ini`), or add a new file `00-ioncube` in your ini directory (in this case `/etc/php.d/00-ioncube` with this content:

   ```
   zend_extension = "<path to your ioncube loader>"
   ```

   As an example with PHP 5.5 and the previous path:

   ```
   zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so"
   ```
5. Restart your webservers:

   ```
   service apache2 restart
   service php5-fpm restart
   ```

Do remember to delete the ionCube Loader Script you installed from your server, since this *might* pose a security risk if left on the server.

In case something goes wrong, check the output your `phpinfo();`, verify that you have the correct Loaders installed (pay attention to thread safety, architecture and PHP version) and get the Loaders manually from [here](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php), and again make sure to choose the right one.

If it still does not work, check your error.log (typically in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error_log`) to see if the Loader is being picked up. The [ionCube Support](http://support.ioncube.com) is also available should there be any problems.

Comment: I have followed all of those instructions but it still doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Is there any message in the error log? Does the Loader appear in the output of your phpinfo?

Comment: Same here. I need to backup an existing host to preserve the old installation. But this software stops working. It's just a copy to a new server and I get a blank page. The loaded is correctly included. It just dies while loading the first ioncube module.