# Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was built with configuration 2.2.0

Tags: php, wordpress, ioncube

I have setup corn file in WordPress but **"Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was built with configuration 2.2.0, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS
Zend Optimizer requires Zend Engine API version 220060519."** this error is coming.

This is my Cron file code.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
    ob_clean();
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    include("../../../wp-config.php");
    error_reporting(0);
    /*
    * snad mail befor 5 day expire post
    */
    $properties = PL()->properties->get_properties(array(
        'status'=> 'publish',
        'before' => PL()->settings->renew_day - 5
    ));

    foreach($properties as $property)   {
        $is_warning_sent = get_post_meta($property->ID,'expire_warning_sent',true);
        if($is_warning_sent != 'true'){
            PL()->properties->send_expire_warning($property->ID);
            echo "Post Exipred warning - ".$property->ID." \n\n";
        }

    }
    /*
    * expire post
    */
    $properties = PL()->properties->get_properties(array(
        'status'=> 'publish',
        'before' =>PL()->settings->renew_day
    ));
    foreach($properties as $property)   {
        PL()->properties->set_post_expire($property->ID);
    }
?>
```

**Out put On Testing mail is**

Cron  /home1/webpixel/public_html/millyclub/wp-content/plugins/property-listing/cron.php
Inbox
    x
Cron Daemon

11:30 AM (28 minutes ago)

to me
Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was built with configuration 2.2.0, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS
Zend Optimizer requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Zend Technologies at http://www.zend.com/ for a later version of Zend Optimizer.

**Warning**:  PHP Startup: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in **Unknown** on line **0**

**Fatal error**:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in **Unknown** on line **0**

Click here to Reply or Forward
45 deleted messages in this conversation. View messages or delete forever.
0.03 GB (0%) of 15 GB used
Manage
Terms - Privacy
Last account activity: 4 minutes ago
Details

Comment: "I have follow this solution and solve the problem" - Great :) There is a feature to mark questions as the accepted answer. Please do this to help other readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ionCube Loader has to match the exact same PHP version that your server is running. In your case, `API220100525,NTS` should refer to PHP 5.4 Non-thread-safe, whereas you currently have installed the Loaders for `220060519`, which should correspond to PHP 5.3 .

You should be able to fix the issue by upgrading your ionCube Loader:

1. Download the newest Loader for your server ([Loader overview](http://ioncu.be/L)).
2. Delete your old Loader files. This includes removing the `zend_extension = <ioncube_loader_path>` entry from your `php.ini`, or from the custom `xxionCube.ini` file in your PHP configuration folder, depending on your installation.
3. Unpack the new Loader(s) to a PHP readable directory.
4. Add or update the relevant `zend_extension` entry to point to your new Loader in your `php.ini` . Make sure that you are matching the exact PHP version.

For installation, you might also want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619848/ioncube-loader-returning-empty-screen/28624883#28624883) I wrote up a few weeks back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have follow this solution and solve the problem.