# How I can upgrade IonCube PHP Loader from v.4.7.5 to v.5.0.0 and higher?

Tags: php, ioncube

How I can upgrade IonCube PHP Loader from v.4.7.5 to v.5.0.0 and higher ?

Please explain to me the process.

My Developer Magento extensions moved to ionСube v.5.0.0

Please help:)

`php -v`: PHP 5.4.28 ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.5

Comment: There shouldn't be any incompatibilities between these versions. Are you experiencing any errors or crashes? Does the new Magento extension no longer work with the v4.7.5 Loader, and, if so, is there any error message displayed? If possible, look through your php error log (e.g. in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, depending on your setup)

Comment: @sebih Thanks a lot! installdir/app/code/local/MagentoDeveloper/Module/Helper/Data.php cannot be decoded\nby this version of the ionCube Loader.\n If you are the administrator of this site\nthen please install the latest version of the ionCube Loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your setup, mostly. In some cases such as CPanel* and certain shared hosting plans, you do not have access to the `php.ini` file, where you can specify which ionCube Loader to use. In these cases, you'll have to wait for your provider to upgrade to a newer ionCube version.

<sub>*[CPanel are working on support for the ionCube Loader v5](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/update-ioncube-to-5-x)</sub>

If you *do* have a setup that allows for a custom `php.ini` file, open up the file and search for an entry such as:

```
zend_extension = "/path/to/ioncube_loader"
```

<sub>Note: On some servers, this entry might be in your `php.d/20-ioncube.ini` file, or something similar</sub> 
 <sub>Note 2: If you have trouble finding your `php.ini` file, take a look at the output of your `phpinfo()` command.</sub>

Make a note of where your current ionCube Loader files are located, download the newest file from [here](http://ioncube.com/L) and replace your old files with the new files. Do make sure to choose the right configuration regarding thread-safety, architecture (32 / 64 bit) and PHP version (in your case PHP 5.4).

Finally, restart Apache/PHP and you should be good to go.

When in doubt, you can comment out or remove the `zend_extension` line from your `php.ini` file, restart Apache/PHP and redo the whole installation from scratch, using the ionCube Loader Wizard ([zip](http://www.ioncube.com/loader-wizard/loader-wizard.zip), [tgz](http://www.ioncube.com/loader-wizard/loader-wizard.tgz)), or contact the [ionCube Support HelpDesk](http://support.ioncube.com) for any specific problems.

I've also written some answers detailing the installation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619848/ioncube-loader-returning-empty-screen/28624883#28624883) which might be of help.

**Summary**: Just overwrite the old files with the new Loader files, restart Apache/PHP. If you run into any problems, reinstall or contact [ionCube Support](http://support.ioncube.com)